# Are int* and int** different types? C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I was curious as to how a pointer to a pointer variable could tell whether it is given just a regular pointer variable or a pointer to a pointer.

I tried this code below and got this error:

```
int x = 3;
int** y = &x;
```

`prog.cpp:7:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int**’ [-fpermissive]`

Is it correct to say `&x` is an `int*` type which is different from an `int**` type and so on?

Comment: Because a pointer to a pointer is still just a pointer to something in memory so I was unsure

Comment: `int*` is a pointer to `int`. `int**` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`. So yes they are very different.

Comment: And yes since `x` is an `int`, applying the address-of operator `&` to `x` will result in an `int*`.

Comment: n addition to the answers below, `int * pi` could be a pointer to the first element of an array of integers, while `int ** ppi` could be a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to integers, such as a variable size matrix (number of rows and the size of each row can vary), also called a "jagged" matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `int *` is a pointer to an integer, and  an `int **` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer.

Answer (score 4):

A pointer(e.g. int*) is a variable that holds a memory address where a value(e.g. int) lives.

&x denotes address of x in the memory, so does y* below.

```cpp
int* y = &x;
```

A pointer of pointer(e.g. int**) is a variable that holds the memory address of a pointer(e.g. int*) of a memory address. Using example above, we can say &y denotes a pointer to a pointer.

```cpp
int** p = &y;
```

Answer (score 0):

`int*` is an integer pointer that holds the address of an integer.

`int**` is an integer double-pointer that holds the address of an integer pointer.

USAGE:

`int* p1 = &i;` Where `i` is an `int` variable.

`int** p2 = &p1;` where `p1` is an `int` pointer.

More: `int*` use for 1D arrays and `int**` use for 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

when declare int* x; means that x holds an address for memory location that contains int data.
but int** x; means x holds address to another variable that contains address to another variable contains int data;

also you should declare a variable before getting its pointer

```
int x=10;
int* px=&x;
int** ppx=&px;
```